# Как запустить двух ботов на одном сервере Aiogram v.2

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть два бота с общей БД, как запустить их на одном сервере? Aiogram v.2 Буду рад любому ответу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возмользуйся каким-нибудь демоном например `cron` или `pm2`